# How to create connection between AWS VPN and our OpenVPN server on our premises?

Tags: amazon-web-services, openvpn

we have a openvpn server version: 2.1.3 running on our premises. We want to connect our AWS VPC to that openvpn server, basically create a site to site vpn. Does anyone know if this can be done with OpenVPN server? and if yes what are the instructions to set this up on our OpenVPN server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Try the following guide:
https://docs.openvpn.net/how-to-tutorialsguides/virtual-platforms/amazon-ec2-appliance-ami-quick-start-guide/

Comment: Link-only answers are strongly discouraged. Please provide content **here** and then link elsewhere for more details.